# How to pass JSON string from ASP.Net to WebAPI Get Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI Get method as shown below

```
// GET api/Employee/5
public tblEmployee GettblEmployee(int id)
{
    tblEmployee tblemployee = db.tblEmployees.Find(id);
    if (tblemployee == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }

     return tblemployee;
 }
```

and i am trying to call that from ASP.NET internet applicaiton

```
HttpClient hc;
hc = new HttpClient();
string uriStr = "http://localhost/api/Employee/";

HttpResponseMessage response = hc.GetAsync(uriStr + "2").Result;

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

ViewBag.Message = obj.ToString();
return View();
```

Now i wanted to pass JSON from ASP website to WebAPI, can someone help me with that. i Googled a lot but i could find only calling from JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a use of [**PostAsJsonAsync**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
using (HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
            {
                var myModel = new Model()
                {
                prop1 = "prop1", prop2 = 1, prop3 = "prop3"
                };
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Employee/", myModel);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                }
            }
```

[**Example**](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#PostingResource)

Comment: hi Shah,, i want to basically pass a JSON from ASP.Net to WebAPI. My WebAPI will return a JSON and i need to receive that from ASP.Net. Can you please help me with both the methods.. is it some kind of custom POST/GET method in WebAPI?

Comment: So you can use above code, `PostAsJsonAsync` is used to post json data, tell me one thing what's does this **api/Employee/** accept as a parameter ? is it some modal or string json ?

Comment: right now it is just a string, i want it to accept a JSON and return a JSON, so what will be there in that method
string strOutput = 'some json string'
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, strOutput);
            return response;